# how to identify which my local ips has connection to another Ip address

Tags: c#, tcp

I have server with two network device and i need to link computers from one side of network to the second network. I need to identify what IP has connection to another ip address.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**IP addresses in C#**

One of the biggest advantages you will notice in the .NET network library is the way IP address/port pairs are handled. .NET defines two classes in the System.Net namespace to handle various types of IP address information:

- IPAddress
- IPEndPoint

Good [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12893/TCP-IP-Chat-Application-Using-C) and example here how to manage this with C#